# Editing the Text file's content based on value of the first 3 colume

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using python 3.9 for below task.
I have text file with following contents(input file);

```
heading1,  heading2,    heading3,   heading4,   heading5,
10,        15,          20,         30,         40
10,        14,          20,         20,         39
10,        15,          20,         10,         29
9,         3,           13,         12,         13
10,        14,          20,          2,          3
10,        15,          20,          10,        10
```

Now using python I am trying to make following new file(output file)

```
heading1,  heading2,    heading3,   heading4,   heading5,
10,        15,          20,         50,         79
10,        14,          20,         22,         42
9,         3,           13,         12,         13
```

Here  in the second file(output file) I am comparing first three column(heading1,heading2 and heading3) and if these same values are presented in other rows I added the heading 4 and heading 5 and make unique row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick hack using pandas.

```
# Read input file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input.txt")

# Dropping unnamed column due to trailing comma in your file
drop_ = [col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed' in col]
df.drop(drop_, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]

# Grouping and transformation
df['heading4'] = df.groupby(['heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3'])['heading4'].transform('sum')
df['heading5'] = df.groupby(['heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3'])['heading5'].transform('sum')
df.drop_duplicates(keep="first", inplace=True)

# Exporting
df.to_csv("output.txt", index=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text file appears to represent CSV.

You can read the CSV and make keys from the values in heading1 and heading2 (as a tuple) then use a dictionary to accumulate changes as follows:

```
import csv

result = {}

with open('input.txt') as infile:
    data = csv.reader(infile)
    columns = [c.strip() for c in next(data) if c]
    for row in data:
        t1, t2, *r = map(int, row)
        vals = result.setdefault((t1,t2), [0]*len(r))
        for i, v in enumerate(r):
            vals[i] += v


print(*columns, sep=',')

for k, v in result.items():
    print(*(list(k)+v), sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
10,15,60,50,79
10,14,40,22,42
9,3,13,12,13
```